# Update field in table defined as a list of symbols

Tags: symbols, kdb

I have the following table:

```
q)t:([]col:`a`b`c; vals:((`abc`def);(enlist `abc);(`$())))

q)t
col vals       
---------------
a   `abc`def   
b   ,`abc      
c   `symbol$()
```

I want to update the entry where `col=c`, that is the empty list of symbols, but I get a `` `length `` error when trying the following query:

```
update vals:(enlist `unknown) from t where 0=count each vals
```

The goal is then to do an `ungroup t` and don't lose the data where `` vals=`symbol$() ``, as currently the ungroup is making me losing some rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you got the `'length` error when you updated some other table, not the one you gave as an example. Your sample code works just fine. The reason why it works on `t` which has only *one* row where `0=count each vals` but fails on tables which have *more than one* row satisfying the where condition is the `update` needs the size of a list of updates to match the target. If a table has more than one row with empty `vals` an update will fail because you provide a list with only one new value.

By the way, if a column were a vector (i.e. a simple list of atoms) then providing an atom as an update would work because atoms are extended to match vectors. But vectors don't.

One way to deal with that is provide a conforming list as Rob suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60543543/93462) or, as an alternative, use [join](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/join/) with [each-left](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right):

```
q)update vals:(vals,\:`unknown) from 6#t where 0=count each vals
col vals
-------------
a   `abc`def
b   ,`abc
c   ,`unknown
a   `abc`def
b   ,`abc
c   ,`unknown
```

Answer (score 3):

To replace your empty symbol lists in the column `vals` with `unknown, you could use something like:

```
q)t:([]col:`a`b`c; vals:((`abc`def);(enlist `abc);(`$())))
q)t:6#t
```

```
update vals:count[i]#enlist enlist `unknown from t where 0=count each vals
```

Output:

```
col vals
-------------
a   `abc`def
b   ,`abc
c   ,`unknown
a   `abc`def
b   ,`abc
c   ,`unknown
```

which uses your approach of finding the values in `val` which have a count of 0.

Or alternatively, you could use something like:

```
update vals:{$[x~`symbol$();enlist `unknown;x]}'[vals] from t
```

Same output as first example:

```
col vals
-------------
a   `abc`def
b   ,`abc
c   ,`unknown
a   `abc`def
b   ,`abc
c   ,`unknown
```

This approach just checks if the value of `val` is empty or not and replaces its value of `val` with `unknown accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider making your own ungroup function if that's ultimately the problem you're trying to solve:

```
q)raze{$[count f:flip x;f;enlist first each x]}'[t]
col vals
--------
a   abc
a   def
b   abc
c
```